# Swift2のidを付与する配列の文がSwift4でエラー

Tags: swift, realm, swift4

Swift2の本を参考に下記のコードをSwift4で作成したところ、idを付与する配列部分で次のエラーが出ています。解決法を教えていただけますか。
＜エラー内容＞
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(Diary, Diary) throws -> Bool'

＜エラー該当部分＞
                    ***diary.id = dataArray.max(by: "id")! + 1***

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    //segueで画面遷移するときに呼ばれる
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        let inputViewController: inputViewController = segue.destination as! inputViewController
        if segue.identifier == "cellsegue"{
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            inputViewController.diary = dataArray[indexPath!.row]

        } else {
            let diary = Diary()
            diary.title = "タイトル"
            diary.body = "本文"
            if dataArray.count != 0 {

                //エラー部分
                ***diary.id = dataArray.max(by: "id")! + 1***

            }
            inputViewController.diary = diary
        }
    }
    //Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(Diary, Diary) throws -> Bool'
```

Answer (score 1):

使うメソッドが間違っています。`max(by:)`は標準ライブラリのメソッドでクロージャを引数にとり、コレクションの要素のうち、最大のものを返すメソッドです。

Realmの最大のプロパティを返す集計関数は、`max(ofProperty:)`です。その部分のコードは下記のように書く必要があります。

```
diary.id = dataArray.max(ofProperty: "id")! + 1
```

Comment: Realmを使ったコードが初完成しました。感謝します。